# Can hot liquid metal be magnetically entrapped?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics, metals, liquid-state

Is it physically possible that a magnetic field be produced or exist; to contain hot, possibly electrically charged, liquid metal, from one side of the liquid metal, into a shape, at zero gravity, without having the electromagnet field emitter making physical contact with the liquid metal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Metal refining employing magnetic levitation melting in cold-crucible induction furnaces is [widely used](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/simcenter/cold-crucible-induction-melting/) in the melting of reactive and pure metals".

Comment: It is entrapped but, it requires gravity to be encased in a solid coil, with in a magnetic field. I need some thing more like a monopole set up with some type of interconnecting magnetic fields that put the liquid metal out in front of the emitter(s) of the field.